# How to disable warnings about anonymous struct in clang?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

I want to use anonymous struct in my C++ program without this warning but keep `-pedantic` flag because I want to know if I'm using any other compiler-extension from Microsoft/GCC on clang. I know that  `-Wno-gnu` but it turn off more than I'm looking for, every gcc's extension supported. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Wno-gnu-anonymous-struct` [should do the job](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23dba35738eb6727).

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work on clang++ 3.0: `warning: unknown warning option '-Wgnu-anonymous-struct' [-Wunknown-warning-option]`